# Change WordPress media from month/year folders to one uploads folder, update site globally?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to uncheck the "organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders" option in my WordPress site, but a previous version of my site had that checkbox checked. There are links and other references to those folders in URLs throughout the site. Is there a way to globally update this? Or perhaps I can fix it with an .htaccess rewrite of some kind?

So that this:

https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/catalog.pdf

Would need to become:

https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/catalog.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) can handle globally updating image paths stored throughout the database (backup the database first for sure).

If everything is in /uploads, searching for '/uploads/XXXX/XX/' and replacing with '/uploads/' should suffice. You could redirect with wildcards in .htaccess but to me the data is still wrong and this approach only masks it.

Scratch the following:

> Make sure the default Media Library location is set to the /catalog
>   folder going forward after unchecking the 'organize my uploads into
>   month- and year-based folders' in Wordpress if you haven't. In
>   wp-config.php, add:
>
> `define('UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads/catalog');`

Edit: misread OP's original question.

Comment: I don't need a "catalog" folder, I was using catalog.pdf as an example file. So no need to edit wp-config.php and you are recommending just using BSR plugin?

Comment: @BBDesign Oh I'm sorry I misread your original question. I updated my answer. Yes I think Better Search Replace will work fine.

Comment: OK, I installed Better Search Replace, however it appears they don't support GREP. So I don't see how this is possible given your solution, no way to have the X characters search for numbers automatically?